# Multiply each row of a scipy sparse matrix by an element of an array, without using multiply

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a csr sparse scipy matrix `X` which is order (10^4, 10^7) elements, and a numpy array `r` with 10^7 elements. I need to multiply each column of the `X` matrix by the corresponding element of `r`, i.e., I need:

```
X_new[:,i] = X[:,i] * r[i]
```

In theory is this done by using `X.multiply(r)`, but the multiply method tries to make `X` dense and this gives a MemoryError. Doing

```
for i in range(len(r)):
    X_new[:,i] = X[:,i] * r[i]
```

Takes impossibly long. I would like to know if anyone has any idea how to do this.

Comment: Is `multiply` really trying to make X dense, or is the resulting matrix (which isn't going to be dense) the issue?

Comment: @Suever The result will be a regular `np.matrix`, not a `scipy.sparse` matrix.